# Read in large compressed json file with pyarrow similar to pandas reader functionality

Tags: pyarrow, apache-arrow

I have a large compressed json file that uncompressed is around~128GBs as a single file. With .gz compression the file is around ~21GBs. I would like to leverage pyarrow to read the file in in chunks and convert to a parquet data-set. I wanted to mimic panda's reader functionality but have run into some issues.

I have the following code working where the compressed json file is read in via pandas read_json into chunks, those chunks are then converted to apache arrow tables, then written out to parquet datasets:

```
reader = pd.read_json("file.json.gz", lines=True, chunksize=5000000) 
for chunk in reader:
   arrow_table = pa.Table.from_pandas(chunk,nthreads=4)
   pq.write_to_dataset(arrow_table,root_path="dir")
```

This code gets me the results I expect however I would like to use apache arrow directly without having to pull into chunked pandas dataframes first then out to an apache arrow table. Primarily I would like to make some gains in performance given the multi-thread reading capability with apache arrow versus pandas read_json.

I have attempted to use the ReadOptions of the pyarrow.json class (https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.json.ReadOptions.html#pyarrow.json.ReadOptions) however, when I run the following code it appears to me that apache arrow is first uncompressing the entire file in memory before reading it in per the block size I have set in the block_size parameter, given the size of the file I am getting out of memory errors if I let the code run.

```
from pyarrow import json 
opts = json.ReadOptions(block_size=4096) 
with json.read_json('file.json.gz',opts) as f: 
    table = f 
    pq.write_to_dataset(table, root_path='dir')
```

In place of the `with json.read_json` I was looking into the input stream functionality similar to a file stream reader but not sure if that is the correct route.

Any recommendations are welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds similar to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-10372. As of the 2.0.0 release, the dataset feature doesn't support reading compressed CSVs or JSON files. Would you mind commenting about your use case on that issue?

Comment: Hey Neal, I will add to the issue, thanks for the response! I am wondering though if there is not a way to do this in pyarrow at all regardless of it it is using the newer dataset functionality or not? I would think I could chunk the file in a similar way into arrow tables instead of dataframes but maybe that is not the case.

Comment: The CSV reader in arrow has a "streaming" option (see https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/csv.html#incremental-reading), however, I don't thing something similar as currently implemented for JSON.

Comment: @joris thanks for that, as you mentioned not currently for JSON and also always single threaded so I am not sure I would see much at all performance gains from pandas but possibly. I have made some progress now getting an Exceeded maximum rows exception when reading.